# How to deal with URI's in Desktop applications using OAuth?

Tags: authentication, oauth

I'm trying to Authenticate to a retail website API and it uses OAuth, which asks me for an URI to redirect after authentication, but I'm developing a desktop application without server-side (I was asked to write it serverless and have requests and DB access made directly from client). What should, if there is any, be my URI in this case (in a general sense, assuming there are no API particularities)? I'm open for some in-depth URI context if found necessary.

I'm aware that authenticating from client-side creates a security vulnerability with in-memory keys, but I'm not playing by my rules.

Didn't try anything yet because I have limited tries before getting the token for a test user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you normally do in desktop apps is to let the app listen on a port for an answer from the OAuth server. E.g. your app will listen on 8080. Then, you can register a redirect URI similar to this: `http://localhost:8080/callback`. Your app will receive the response with the code and will be able to exchange it for an access token.

Many authorization servers allow registering the localhost URI without the port so that any port can be used for the redirect. E.g. you register `http://localhost/callback` then use `http://localhost:8080/callback`. This is useful to allow for a more flexible port management by your app. Your app can then start listening on a random available port instead of risking having a conflict on the fixed port number.